# What are Non-overlapping community detection algorithms that I can use using Python iGraph?

Tags: python, igraph, social-networking, sna

What are Non-overlapping community detection algorithms that I can use using Python iGraph?

I tried to search a lot on this but I cound't find answer, please guide me here...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know most of the community detection algorithms that are implemented in iGraph are for non-overlapping networks.

A quote from the [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep30750) *A Comparative Analysis of Community Detection Algorithms on Artificial Networks* by Yang et. al. goes like this:

> In this paper, we evaluate eight different state-of-the-art community detection algorithms available in the
>   “igraph” package, which is a widely used collection of network analysis tools in R, Python, C and C++, on the
>   LFR benchmark for undirected, unweighted graphs with non-overlapping communities.

[This blog](https://yoyoinwanderland.github.io/Community-Detection/) post does a good job at comparing various community detection algorithms available in iGraph.